# Is it better to start an existing Docker container or always run a new one (and manually remove the old ones)?

Tags: docker, automation, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

What would be the most friendly solution for CI/CD and automated workflows? Always forcing a new run would mean we always use the latest image, but it creates additional work in terms of having to remove the old, inactive containers (especially if they're named the same).

Would always running a new container and not naming it, and then periodically cleaning everything with `docker container prune` be the way to go? I'm looking for what's best practice.

Comment: Read about `docker-compose`, seems suitable for your use-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a CI workflow especially:

- Every build creates a new image with a unique tag.
- Integration tests always create new containers with that new image.  (There isn't an existing container you could reuse with the right image; you can generate a unique name within the context of a particular build.)
- When you deploy, create new containers with the new image.  (Or update a Compose setup or Kubernetes objects to have the new tag, which will cause new containers to be created.)

Deleting and recreating containers is extremely routine.  The `docker build; docker run` sequence also means your container's startup is always starting from a known place, and you won't usually have old temporary files or stale pid files that need cleanup.  You also can't change the image underneath an existing container, so in the context of a CI system you *must* create a new container with the newly-built image.

IME there's not a lot of downside to always using `docker run`.  `docker exec` is a debugging tool, and while it's extremely useful, it doesn't have a place here.  You shouldn't need `docker start` at all.